# Fastest way to mass update Sitecore user profile field

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I need to update a field in all user profiles on my Sitecore 8 instance. I've used Powershell for similar tasks in the past, but with well over a million users, this is absurdly slow. Is there a faster/better way to update user accounts en masse?

Comment: Share your code maybe we can make it faster. Think about "multithreading"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile properties of an account are stored in the SQL database (assuming you're using the standard authentication system.

There is a pattern used to serialise the data.  Depending on the nature of the change you are trying to make, you may be able to get away with a SQL query.

That's the fastest way by a zillion miles, but for millions of updates, you'll need a heap of log file space.

Edit: The pattern is trivial to decode so I won't insult you be documenting it here.  Check the "aspnet_" tables in the Core database.